# how to set the simulator configuration

Tags: iphone, xcode, simulator

I want to change the settings of my simulator on Xcode.
e.g set my battery life 20%, set my signal low (-100), put my iPhone in air plane mode etc.
is there anyway I can do those things on my simulator in Xcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things that you cannot trust the simulator for, memory, performance, graphics etc... I do think Apple should allow some functionality to simulate bad network conditions (either non existent or fluctuating), airplane mode and so on. The only thing you can do with the simulator is trigger a memory warning and plug yourself completely of the network. Bad network conditions are particularly hard to debug. You can take your laptop and iOS device in the train and do it there, on 3G (which is a real pain).

Comment: Xcode on Lion comes with a "bad network" simulator, throttling speeds and introducing errors. You'll find it somewhere under /Developer and it's a Preference Pane.

Answer (score 9):

For the network part: you could install Apple's Network Link Conditioner Prefpane which comes with Xcode. On Lion located in: 
`/Developer/Applications/Utilities/Network Link Conditioner`

[image: Network Link Conditioner]

Comment: Hey, that's pretty cool. It wasn't installed on my machine by default but it can be found in XCode -> Open Developer Tools -> More Developer Tools -> Hardware IO

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to set those conditions on the simulator. If you want to test with those conditions then you will have to use a real device.

Comment: ohh screw me... :(, tx anyway sosborn